# Mono - GTK (Linux) / Cocoa (Mac OS) in one Solution?

Tags: cocoa, mono, gtk

It's possible to create project (solution in mono) when before build for target OS is decided what GUI use?

I have:

- Windows - C# WinForms
- Linux - C# Winforms -> GTK+
- MacOS X - C# GTK+ but I want to replace it with Cocoa binds

its possible to have this in one solution?

Comment: All of them (WinForms project, GTK# project, and MonoMac/Xamarin.Mac project) can be put into the same solution (.sln) file. I am not sure what is your question indeed. Vote to close this question unless the author provides more details.

Comment: I start using XWT by answer from @knocte, I have to fix some functions, but it looks great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use [XWT](https://github.com/mono/xwt/) (although in the Windows case you would have WPF instead of Windows.Forms)